# warning:lib openflow _01 fields ignored due to unspecified prerequisites nw_src nw _dst

Tags: python, api, mininet, pox

This question has been asked  previously and I have tried everything given in the answers but still getting the same warning. I am using code in this [link](http://csie.nqu.edu.tw/smallko/sdn/mySDN.pdf)
(lab4.py & lab4_controller.py). I am creating a separate file of topology in `/mininet/examples` and trying to access the switches using pox controller from another terminal but getting the above warning.

Comment: You should post your code here, links can change over time and the question would become useless.

Answer (score 3):

this warning means that you did just specified higher layer parameter without lower parameter specified first.

Please refer this [link](https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki#POXWiki-Whatdoesthe%27Fieldsignoredduetounspecifiedprerequisites%27warningmean%3F)

Comment: I cannot access that link: Access is Forbidden